# Computing confidence intervals for individual factor levels and individual response variables in one-way MANOVA

Tags: anova, confidence-interval, manova

In the context of one-way MANOVA testing (one factor with multiple levels of treatment), after we've rejected the null hypothesis of no difference in means between groups (levels), i.e. after we rejected $$H_0: \forall_i \boldsymbol\tau_i=\mathbf{0},$$ it's advised to check for confidence intervals (CI) for pairwise contrasts, i.e. CIs for $\tau_{ik}-\tau_{jk}$.

However, if possible, I'm looking for CI for each component (dependent variable) for each treatment level, i.e. a CI for each $\tau_{ik}$ (dependent variable $k$, treatment level $i$). How can one compute these CIs?

P.S.: I'm assuming $\boldsymbol \tau_i=\boldsymbol\mu_l-\boldsymbol \mu \in \mathbb{R}^p$, where $p$ is the number of response/dependent variables.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I did not downvote, but to be honest, I don't understand the question. @RichardHardy

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question either but the only thing that comes to mind is that you can compute confidence intervals on the canonical functions (optimal combinations of dv's).

Comment: You refer to "both" null hypotheses, but you haven't written a model which would suggest what the two nulls might be, let alone what the nulls were. Is this a bivariate response? Is it a two-group situation? What were you interested in testing, exactly?

Comment: Quick searches for *factor effect MANOVA* and *treatment effect MANOVA* both turn up a lot of hits ... do none of the first page or so of hits on either offer insight on your question?

Comment: You're right. Both hyp, because I was thinking of allowing for the two-way MANOVA. I'll restrict it to one-way then, by giving a specific null hyp.

Comment: @Glen_b My search didn't result in any useful hit...

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I believe your question is quite a bit clearer now.

Comment: I still don't understand this question (cc @Glen_b). You wrote that it's now about one-way manova, but still ask about individual factor effects. One-way means one factor. It seems you are using terminology in a non-standard way.

Comment: @amoeba I think he's after the CI's for effects for the levels within the factor (which I think has some issues just as they would for an ordinary anova -- but those are within the scope of an answer)

Comment: This makes sense @Glen_b, thanks. I guess Anoldman should clarify what he means by CI in the multivariate situation. If there are 10 dependent variables, what kind of a CI is he after?

Comment: I guess the interior of a ten-dimensional ellipsoid. Note that if $X$ is $MVN(\mu,\Sigma)$ then  $(X-\mu)^T\,\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)$ should be chi-square.

Comment: @amoeba 1 factor with multiple treatment levels. I'm interested in the CI for the components of each treatment vector. I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @Glen_b What type of issues would we have in an univariate ANOVA?

Comment: The issue I was talking about is that the meaning of coefficients for the individual factor levels depends on the particular coding used. In some cases they're not necessarily particularly useful things to estimate.

Comment: @oldman that information in your reply to amoeba needs to be in your question

Comment: @Glen_b Here, I'm thinking of $\tau_l = \mu_l-\mu$. Similarly for univariate case?

Comment: Okay, that's another thing that should be made clear in your question!

Comment: @Glen_b I'm really sorry for my bad wording, and the need to redefine the question so many times. I hope now it's good enough.

Comment: What is still not clear is why you are not satisfied with an obvious solution of computing a CI for each dependent variable and for each factor level separately? I.e. for each $\tau_{ik}$?

Comment: @amoeba I don't understand your last comment... Could you please elaborate a bit more, maybe in an answer? Thanks

Comment: Well, you have a bunch of treatments and a bunch of outcome variables. For each treatment and for each outcome variable you have a bunch of numbers. You can obviously compute a CI around the mean of this bunch of numbers. And then repeat this for every outcome variable and for every treatment. This is obvious. I presume you want some other procedure, so I am asking why you are not satisfied with this one.

Comment: @amoeba If X_{in} is an $n$th draw from population/treatment $i$, then $X_{in}=\mu +\tau_i + \epsilon_{in}$. How can you disentangle a CI for the mean from the treatment. Maybe the procedure you're talking about suits me just fine... Could you please write an answer with more details? Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it, what is there to disentangle?? If for one treatment you have values {1,2,3,4,5} and for another treatment you have values {11,12,13,14,15}, then what's the problem saying that the CI of the first treatment is 3±1 (or something like that) and the CI for the second treatment is 13±1?

Comment: @amoeba For a CI you usually need to know the distribution (giving us a level of confidence for the CI) of a Pivot Variable or sth similar that allows you to isolate the parameter of interest. In this case, what's the distribution? and how can you be sure that it's not dependent on unknown parameters?

Comment: Which unknown parameters?? Sorry, I will not be posting an answer, because I don't really understand the issue here. MANOVA assumes normal errors. Computing CI as mean ± 1.96 st. errors of the mean also assumes normal errors. To be clear, I am not saying that this is the best approach. But this is an obvious approach, so I asked why it's not satisfactory.

Comment: @amoeba I don't intend to frustrate you or make you angry, sorry. That's why I suggested an answer where you could get into more detail.  The unknown parameters are $\mu, \tau_l$, and $\Sigma$ from the error terms.

Comment: It's okay :) Your question has my +1. Hopefully somebody else will post a good answer and we will both learn smth. I will now edit for clarity (feel free to edit further).